# Spring Boot+Thymeleaf doesn't resolve login.html

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have basically copied the tutorial to use Spring Web Security with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

For configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
}}
```

For security in `public class WebSec extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/users*").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/users/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll();
}
```

All html files are under

```
/src/main/resources/templates
```

Now, `home.html` is found nicely. However whenever anything requires the login page, the `login.html` in the same folder is not found and the error is:

```
Error resolving template "login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: I saw that before ... maybe. Could you please try ...setViewName("login.html");

Comment: @Flocke Same, now "login.html" is not found. :(

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Do not call your template files the same as your routes. The problem can be solved by naming the file `login_template.html` or something. Or even better, change the line:

```
 registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
```

to just

```
 registry.addViewController("/login");
```

I found a hint to this behaviour in the javadocs for `ViewControllerRegistration.setViewName`.